# OpenFileInput does NOT throw FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

I'm participating in an online Android course and have (so far) gotten no response on their forum to this issue. I'm using Android Studio on Windows 8.1.

I have the following function to read a file and load an adapter:

```
private void loadItems() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String title = null;
        String priority = null;
        String status = null;
        Date date = null;

        while (null != (title = reader.readLine())) {
            priority = reader.readLine();
            status = reader.readLine();
            date = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(reader.readLine());
            mAdapter.add(new ToDoItem(title, Priority.valueOf(priority),
                    Status.valueOf(status), date));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != reader) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. I don't find the file named by the constant FILE_NAME anywhere on my hard drive. If the file doesn't exist shouldn't **openFileInput()** throw **FileNotFoundException**?
2. Why does **InputStreamReader** not throw an error?
3. Via the debugger, I've watched as The logic guarding entry into the WHILE construct happily allows a null value in the **title** variable to enter the loop. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance for any light anyone can shed!!

Markb

Comment: "I don't find the file named by the constant FILE_NAME anywhere on my hard drive" -- that is because your computer is running Windows. Android is not Windows. The file would be in the Android environment (emulator or device), not in a Windows filesystem.

Comment: Regarding #1: Do you execute this code on your android device? In that case, the file must be on the devices's storage, not on your hard drive. Regarding #2: It should, unless the file really does not exist. Regarding #3: In your loop, you call `getLine` three more times without guarding against `null` values.

Comment: @CommonsWare - That's what I thought, but the 16 or so forum members who read my post at the online course seem to be unaware of that possibility. There's also no app to view the file system on the android emulator, so I had to ask this question here. Thanks!!

Comment: @still_learning - Thanks for the validation (see CommonsWare's comment). One thing still puzzles me, however. If I kill the emulator, doesn't that release all the local storage and files? But when I restarted the IDE, the problem was still there. Does the app hold on to the file?I told the course staff that they needed more robust error handling too! I'll be posting these comments back to the course forum